# Discord bot verify system

Tags: javascript, discord.js

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
module.exports = {
 name: 'verify',
 execute(message, args) {
  const embed3 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
   .setTitle('Verify')
   //.setColor(0xff0000)
   .setColor('9400D3')
   .setDescription('Click on the ✅ to acess the server!');
  //.setFooter('Coded by GalaxyBoy#9353,Iron#0447 and blackout#8324')

  message.channel.send(embed3).then((sentEmbed) => {
   sentEmbed.react('✅');

   const filter = (reaction, user) => {
    return (
     ['✅'].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id === message.author.id
    );
   };

   sentEmbed
    .awaitReactions(filter, { max: 1, time: 60000, errors: ['time'] })
    .then((collected) => {
     const reaction = collected.first();

     if (reaction.emoji.name === '✅') {
      message.reply('This part is working.');
     }
    })
    .catch((collected) => {
     message.reply('you reacted with neither a thumbs up, nor a thumbs down.');
    });
   `enter code here`;
  });
 },
};
```

How could I modify this code so that it gives me a role instead of just saying that it is working? I have tried doing several things but none seem to work, everything that I do instead goes straight to catch(collected). Does anyone have a solution to fix this? If so it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`GuildMemberRoleManager.add()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberRoleManager?scrollTo=add)

```js
if (reaction.emoji.name === '✅') {
 message.member.roles.add('Role ID');
}
```

Comment: I'm such an idiot, I tried everything but the obvious. Thank you.

Comment: Glad I could help. Please mark my answer as accepted if it solved your problem so others can see it easier if they have the same question :)